# Is there a way in Aarch64 to branch to an address on a stack while preserving all registers?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I have access to a stack/memory which has some address stored on it (I know here it is and can load it).
I also need to preserve all GPR registers in their current state once I branch to that address.
I can store them to stack to get some scratch regs but I need to restore them before the final branch.
Is it possible to do on AArch64 (v8-a) and if so, how?
I think on older Arm v7 you could just `LDR PC, <addr>` but that's no longer possible. Maybe it's somehow possible to hijack `elr`/`eret` for this?

Comment: Are you in full control of EL1 or not?

Comment: I presume you don't have control of the code at that branch address target?  Is the target code well known or highly variable?  If that target code is well known you might identify a register that it overwrites (writes to without reading) and use that register with impunity.

Comment: it's possible, that's how interrupt handlers work. It's totally unclear from that description what is initial state for that saving/restoring. Have a look on `MSR SPSel, #Imm4 ; Used to select the Stack Pointer, between SP_EL0 and SP_ELx`. You could select some EL specific stack and save anything you need.

Comment: @ErikEidt problem is - target code is sort of arbitrary (can be multiple targets with different reg defs), There  are ways to control it but it's the last resort.

Comment: @Siguza at the point I need to do a branch the state is in EL0.

Comment: I believe you will need to ask the operating system for assistance with this one.  On UNIX, the relevant system call is usually called `sigreturn`.  Which operating system are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz linux-based

Comment: @DanM. Then `sigreturn` is probably the right system call, though it's poorly documented.